# Ayuda con la manera de salir de un dialogo de wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Me gustaría pedir ayuda con algo que por más que busco y le doy vueltas no consigo hacer. Posiblemente sea fácil la solución pero estoy ofuscado y no doy con la vuelta.

Bien en wxpython tengo una ventana de dialogo la cual deseo que se cierre tanto con un botón dedicado a ello como pulsando escape.

Para ello tengo esto:

```
    self.closeBTN = wx.Button(Panel, wx.ID_ANY, _("&Close"))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose, self.closeBTN)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.onEsc)

def onEsc(self, event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
        ConfigFileSave()
        self.Destroy()
    else:
        event.Skip()

def onClose(self, event):
    ConfigFileSave()
    self.Destroy()
```

Bien esto funciona perfectamente, pero ahora mis preguntas.

1º Seria posible tener ligado las dos acciones a un solo def, algo a si:

```
Def onPrueba(self, event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
        ConfigFileSave()
        self.Destroy()
    elif >capturar el evento del botón al ser pulsado< == >saber cuando fue pulsado el botón<:
        ConfigFileSave()
        self.Destroy()
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

El planteamiento anterior lo conseguiría si no me equivoco definiendo los eventos a si:

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPrueba, self.closeBTN)
    self. closeBTN.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.onPrueba)
```

2º Hay alguna otra manera de hacer lo que pretendo?

Espero haberme explicado y muchas gracias de antemano.

Cordiales saludos

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues en la lista de Python en Español me contestaron.

https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-es

Dejo aquí una posible solución y sigo abierto a saber si hubiese otras formas de hacerlo.

```
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose, self.closeBTN)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.onClose)

def onClose(self, event):
    if event.GetEventType() == 10012:
        ConfigFileSave()
        self.Destroy()
    else:
        keyCode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keyCode == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            ConfigFileSave()
            self.Destroy()
        event.Skip()
```